# Parse childs in XML python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have a XML code like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coureurs>
<coureur>
<nom>Patrick</nom><hair>Inexistants</hair>
</coureur>


</coureurs>
```

And i want to print that:

```
  Patrick inexistents
      Etc...

For now my code is :
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(file.xml)
for coureur in tree.xpath("/coureurs/coureur/nom"):
print(user.text)
```

but it returns blank, when i do:
   for user in tree.xpath("/coureurs/coureur/hair"):
it only returns hair. what should i do?

Comment: sorry its not he exeact code the xml is wrong on that one but for mine its right.

Comment: i edited it. corrected the </user>

Comment: I do not think that is the correct xml either, if that was correct xml , then the xpath - `for user in tree.xpath("/users/user/hair"):` would not be working, it would not even return the hair, but you said it returns the hair in your question.

Comment: aand now? (this is the real code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not able to reproduce the issue with the xml and code you provided. But seems like you have left out a lot of xml , and most probably the `XPATH` may not be working for you if `coureurs` is not the direct root of the xml (or its direct child) .

In such cases, you can use the following XPATH to get each `coureur` node in the xml (that is the child of a `coureurs` node) -

```
//coureurs/coureur
```

This would give you all `<coureur>` tag elements from the xml , and then you ca iterate over that to print it's child's text . Example Code -

```
for user in tree.xpath('//coureurs/coureur'):
    for child in user:
        print(child.text,end=" ")
    print()
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
In [26]: s = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
   ....: <coureurs>
   ....: <coureur>
   ....: <nom>Patrick</nom><hair>Inexistants</hair>
   ....: </coureur>
   ....: </coureurs>"""

In [28]: tree = etree.fromstring(s.encode())

In [35]: for user in tree.xpath('//coureurs/coureur'):
   ....:     for child in user:
   ....:         print(child.text,end=" ")
   ....:     print()
   ....:
Patrick Inexistants
```

Comment: No , those are my interpreter prompt , use the code from above the example/demo .

Comment: But, in the code above (mine) where do you see <user>?

Comment: Sorry didn't get your question. what do you mean?

Comment: why : for user in tree.xpath

Comment: and not : for coureur in tree.xpath?

Comment: its just a variable name you can define it as anything, just make sure to use the same variable you define there in the next line.

Comment: If you want you can define it as - `for asldnaksjdadhbdkshfajkshfbasdjkfhsabkfhasbfkjashfbsakdhsadvas in tree.xpath` . And wouldn't change a thing . Though just need to make sure you are accessing it the same way.

Comment: @wikiwiki Also Why was the answer unaccepted? Did this not work for you? Are you facing any issues?

Comment: File "Parser.py", line 8
    print(child.text,end="")
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7 ?

Comment: yep :/ should i move to py3?